# Points tangent to two same sized circles

Tags: geometry

I have two circles that are the same diameter, they are at least 2 times the diameter apart, so there will be always 4 tangent lines. I need to calculate coordinates of intersection of circles and tangent lines - H, I, G, F, E, J, K, L on the drawing. I know center locations of circles and their diameter.

[Here](https://cp-algorithms.com/geometry/tangents-to-two-circles.html#problems) is a solution that i modifying to my needs but i can't figure it out.

I am familiar with high-school level math so i understand basic trigonometry and vector operations. But i was few years ago that i used that knowledge so figuring out how to approach this problem is quite challenging for me.

This [calculator](https://www.123calculus.com/en/tangent-lines-two-circles-page-7-60-430.html) does exactly what i want (result under `Coordinates` section) but i need formulas.

[Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvTPE.png)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? What tools (vectors, trig, ...) can you use?* etc) This information helps people avoid wasting time explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. ... Here, diameters $GH$ and $IK$ are perpendicular to $AC$. Also, the internal tangents cross at the midpoint (say, $M$) of $AC$, making four identical right triangles (like $\triangle MAF$). Does this help you?

Comment: I tried coping solution from here https://cp-algorithms.com/geometry/tangents-to-two-circles.html#problems but i couldn't figure out way to convert line formulas to coordinates.  This is not a textbook problem (I need solution for hobby coding project) so I can use what ever tools i want.

Comment: Knowing that you have access to a solution may save people time in crafting their own responses, so thanks for that. (You should include the reference in the body of the question. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.) ... *"I can use what ever tools i want."* Okay, but what tools do you *know*? (Again, say so *in the question*.)